# I want to find the 6th root of z which lies in a specific domain.

Tags: complex-analysis, roots-of-unity

Let $z=-3+8.5i$,   $\arg z \in (-\pi,\pi]$.

Find the $6th$ root of $z$ which which lies in: $(2\pi\frac{4}{6},2\pi\frac{5}{6})$

Provide an answer to decimal places.

What is $\theta$ if the answer is in the form $\sqrt[6]{z}=r^{\frac1 6}e^{im}$ ?

where $m= \frac{\theta + 2\pi k}{6} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the answer gives you a very strong hint as to the method you should use.

You should express you complex number like that:
$z=\alpha e^{i\phi}$

In that case $\alpha=\sqrt{3^2+8.5^2}$

and $\tan{\phi}=-\dfrac{8.5}{3}$

I think you can go from there...

Comment: The equation $\tan \phi=-8.5/3$ is not enough. It's amazing the number of occasions I have seen this done wrong. The argument is here $\pi-\arctan(8.5/3)$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Of course this is not enough. You saw as well that I did not finish to solve the problem. Since the key points are the domains and the sixth root of $z$, I only started the work and tried to give a useful hint as to how to proceed. That's why I did not gave the angle, but the formula that can lead (if handled properly) to the angle...

Comment: correct but finding the argument is just part of the question I need to find the 6th root of unity within the domain shown above. But thank you guys for helping

Comment: I was maybe a bit rough, but I have seen this "$\tan \phi$" mistake too many times, so I felt I had to comment. Answers should be meant to be useful for other readers. @Rayhaanbhikha Once you have the argument, you just have to divide by $6$ then find how many times to add or subtract $\pi/3$ to make the new argument fall in the right interval.